# Which template do you edit to change doctype in Magento checkout?

Tags: magento

Which template do you edit to change doctype on the Magento checkout page?

I am trying to implement a design change using an alternative package/theme for mobiles using the Magento's HTML5, "iphone" template but I have been having problems with doctypes on certain pages.

The checkout is one such page. Try as I have I haven't been able find the template.

IT is driving me insane.

Any help appreciated.

Using Magento 17.0.2

Comment: activate the template hints to find out what phtml file is responsible of your design

Answer (score 0):

First go to `layout/checkout.xml`.  Copy that into your design if it's not already there so you can change the section that references `template/page/1column.phtml` as the template.  Override that with your own file and in there you'll be able to set any doctype.

If you want to change the doctype globally, and not just on the checkout page, you can just edit your `1column.phtml`.

As you make changes to these files go into the admin and clear your cache if you don't see the updates immediately.

Comment: Hi think but I'm a bit confused. The file checkout.xml is already located in my theme / layout directory. Not sure what changes I need to make to that file as I've never changed the doctype using xml. Or are you saying create new file to replace 1column.phtml one that I changed the doctype on???

Comment: If you want to change the doctype for the whole site simply edit 1column.phtml. If you want to change the doctype for *only* the checkout, you have to tell it to use a new template in checkout.xml. Hope that helps!

Comment: And see my edit: if you make changes and they don't seem to show up, go into the admin and clear the cache.

Comment: Matt, I edited the checkout.xml file like so: <reference name="root">
        <action method="setTemplate"><template>page/1column_checkout.phtml</template></action>
    </reference>
I then refreshed the cache but I'm still not seeing the correct document type. I'm still baffled. Is that what you meant?

Comment: Yes. It doesn't seem to be referencing your new phtml file? That's odd. Are you sure your checkout.xml file is copied into the right directory within your custom theme?

Comment: Yes, quite sure. The theme has been installed using matched expressions for mobile devices etc. I renamed the theme so instead of iphone I named the directory as "my_iphone" but I'm wondering the theme name at the top of the page is was default_iphone - I'm wondering if that is causing an issue? The thing is everything else looks okish, so I really don't know what is wrong...

Comment: Sorry I wasn't very clear in the above comment (last one). It is still not working. The files look to be in the correct directories and everything should be working as far as I can tell.  Baffled.

Comment: The last thing I could think of checking is that theme name. It must match the theme selected in the admin. My guess is it's falling back to using another theme.

Comment: Magento appears to be doing just that Matt. It is going back to the base/default directory - I added some test text to the cart.phtml page and it displayed. I don't know what to do about this now. As for theme names, I don't understand why the home page, category and product pages are displaying ok but checkout, account, customer and login pages are not.

Comment: I have also renamed all instances of the template names in the theme so it reflects the correct theme name. It is dropping back to base/default directory

Answer (score 0):

Go to app/design/frontend/default/yourtheme/template/page folder, then edit the 1-column.phtml, 2columns-left.phtml, 2columns-right.phtml and 3 columns.phtml